# Number of automorphisms of binary tree

Tags: graph-theory

I've been assigned with a task of creating a tree $T$ for which $|AUT(T)|=2^n$. Is this possible? I know how to construct a tree for which $|AUT(T)|=2^{{2^n}-1}$ but I'm having troubles with the assigned one. Could you please help me?

Comment: Probably your question is better placed on math.stackexchange.com. But here is one way to do it.  First, make a rigid tree with $n$ leaves, for example, by placing them all on different heights. Then, give each of those leaves two successors, which could be swapped. Any set of the leaves now causes an automorphism of the new tree, so there are $2^n$ automorphisms.